# Javascript PHPMyAdmin Like Field selection (ctrl + arrow keys)

Tags: javascript, phpmyadmin

Any body knows how PHP My Admin shifts focus from one field to other in add new table or other forms using <kbd>CTRL + DOWN ARROW</kbd> keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When on the same row just find the **closest td** then switch to the **previous** or the **next** one, find the input and focus it. example with next:

```
$(this).closest('td').next().find('input').focus();
```

When on different row find the **closest tr** then switch to **next** or **previous** one. Using **the index of the current td** find the **index of the new td**, find the input and focus it. exemple wih next:

```
$(this).closest('tr').next().find('td').eq($(this).closest('td').index()).find('input').focus();
```

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roine/7quJq/1/) to demonstrate.

Comment: ctrl + keyboard arrow, works on my chrome. I found out why, just add jquery on the left panel, I have updated my fiddle

Comment: One comment, that your solution dont work on Ubuntu 12.04. Changing it from CTRL to SHIFT worked... I wonder why not CTRL

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 12.04 with chrome and it works fine using ctrl+ arrow keys

Comment: Yes, that what I was thinking about... may be some settings are not working properly